# SQL UPDATE on with data from same table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update, temp-tables, insert-update

I have a next situation with a table, Need to update rows from rows in same table, as you see here:

TABLE

| ID | SN | FID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12345 | 1 |
| 2 | 1122 | 2 |
| 3 | 12345-RG | NULL |
| 4 | 1122-RG | NULL |

I need to UPDATE row 3 from row 1 Column FID(Same SN, different ending only on the end -RG)
Update row 4 FROM row 2 Column FID(Same SN, different ending -RG)

So the result should be:

TABLE

| ID | SN | FID |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 12345 | 1 |
| 2 | 1122 | 2 |
| 3 | 12345-RG | 1 |
| 4 | 1122-RG | 2 |

I have tried many ways but I don't get with this... I tried declaring a temp table and trying to compare from there but still with this issue...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Asuming `[SN]` is being augmented with `-RG`

**Example**

```
with cte as (
Select * 
      ,NV = max(FID) over (partition by replace(SN,'-RG','') )
 From YourTable
)
Update cte set FID = NV 
 --Where FID is null  -- Optional
```

**The Updated Table**

```
ID  SN          FID
1   12345       1
2   1122        2
3   12345-RG    1
4   1122-RG     2
```

Comment: -RG on serial number SN is already create, but FID is NULL, so I want to update FID only, comparing the -RG item with same item without the -RG (they are same serial number, but different ending of the serial number)

Comment: @user3128539 Pretty sure that is what we are doing.   Perhaps you can confirm on a temp table.

Comment: @user3128539 take a peek at https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=c06dda445a7821821c4a75fd588e2735

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help and time!